# Data validation in Spark Structured Streaming - ETL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Structured Streaming Programming and I want to perform ETL.
I have some validation/sanity check, help to deside BAD records.

[image: Input and Output Data Sample]

My Code:

```
    val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("id",StringType,true),StructField("lastName",StringType,true),StructField("age",StringType,true),StructField("dept",StringType,true),StructField("sal",StringType,true),StructField("gender",StringType,true),StructField("status",StringType,true)))    
val path : String = "F:/Hadoop/Data"
import spark.implicits._
//RegEx expression to check input data
val col1p = "\\d{3}".r
val col2p = "[a-zA-Z]".r
val col3p = "\\d{3}".r
val col4p = "[10|20|30]".r
val col5p = "[0-9]".r
val col6p = "[M|F]".r
var st : String = "1" //Good Record

//Read input file
val empRaw = spark
.readStream
.option("sep", "~")
.schema(schema)
.csv(path)

//Write output
empRaw.writeStream
.outputMode("Append")
.format("console")
.option("checkpointLocation", "F:/Hadoop/Data/log0")
.start()

spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

Below is sanity check/ETL check. Not sure where to apply.
Or is there any other way to do the same.

```
empRaw.rdd.map(r => {if (col1p.findFirstMatchIn(r(0).toString()).isEmpty || 
   (col1p.findFirstMatchIn(r(1).toString()).isEmpty) ||
   (col1p.findFirstMatchIn(r(2).toString()).isEmpty) ||
   (col1p.findFirstMatchIn(r(3).toString()).isEmpty) ||
   (col1p.findFirstMatchIn(r(4).toString()).isEmpty) ||
   (col1p.findFirstMatchIn(r(5).toString()).isEmpty)) 
  {st = "0"}
  Row(r(0).toString().toInt,r(1).toString(),r(2).toString().toInt,r(3).toString().toInt,
      r(4).toString().toInt,r(5).toString(),st)})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`udf` is helpful for this usecase

### Imports

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import spark.implicits._
```

### Create UDF

```
val validate = udf((id: String,
                    lname: String,
                    age: String,
                    dept: String,
                    sal: String,
                    gender: String) => {
  //Feel free to improve this condition check code
  if (id.matches("\\d{3}") &&
    lname.matches("[a-zA-Z]") &&
    age.matches("\\d{3}") &&
    dept.matches("[10|20|30]") &&
    sal.matches("[0-9]") &&
    gender.matches("[M|F]")) 1
  else 0
})
```

### Using the UDF

```
empRaw.withColumn("status", 
  validate($"id", $"lastName", $"age", $"dept", $"sal", $"gender"))
```